# program for sniffing data from packet

Tags: embedded

I want to sniff packets from stream of packets that are transmitter from CC1350 chip -SimpleLink Ultra-Low Power Dual Band Wireless Microcontroller .
I want to write a function that gets from the stream a packet and tell if it's ok or not ok - it's valid packet or not valid packet -
the validation packet or not valid is related to the size of the syncWordLength if it's for instance 20 or less than 20 , what's confusing me that I dont know inside my packet which bits from where to where does the data of syncWorldLength is stored .. any help?
Proprietary packets is used ..

I can't by wireshark get sniff the packet because it's on chip packet ..

thanks alot

Comment: Did you perhaps mean syncWordLength? Apart from that your question is not entirely clear.  It is a lot of probably irrellavant text if all you are asking is the location of a specific field in a packet.

Comment: Yes exactly, Im asking for that because I want to get the packet and get that data of syncWorldLength from there .. why it's irrelevant?

Comment: I repeat, do you mean syncWordLength rather than syncWorldLength?

Comment: Yup i mean that

Comment: TI claims to have a "Packet Sniffer PC Software". Why can't you use that one?

Comment: because I need to upgrade it to something else afterwards ..